# Google login with react using as wordpress backend

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, oauth

Considering having an old app written in WordPress and I want to convert it step-by-step into an app written with modern frameworks React + NodeJS.

Right now my first thought is firstly create a Frontend in React and use custom-created API endpoints in WordPress.

My technical difficulty is with Google OAuth authentication: considering that I am acquiring a token on React Frontend how can I use this token to make API requests to the WordPress backend?

Comment: Maybe you could use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-login-with-eve-online-google-facebook/

Comment: @tpliakas I had it already in mind, the only question is if I can make authenticated REST API calls through react frontend, ευχαριστω!

Comment: ofc you can. Get the token using https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library, and use fetch or axios to POST to wordpress API with the plugin

Comment: you're welcome Χρήστο! Will make that an answer so other can see it, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be like this:

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library and get the token in your react app.

Then use axios or fetch to POST to wordpress API using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-login-with-eve-online-google-facebook/

Both the lib & plugin have examples, too.

Comment: Please be careful, this plugin contains several critical vulnerabilities:: https://lana.codes/lanavdb/12bb3c02-45f1-4ce8-8a5a-8b44352cf7fc/ and https://lana.codes/lanavdb/071fa6eb-2e54-43a1-b37f-1e562988b7d4/